# R Correlated time-series

Tags: r, time-series, correlation

I have multiple time series and want to study whether certain events happen at relatively the same time in the different series.  For example say I have x1 and x2 which are both time-series but from different sources, and I want to know whether x1 increases/decreases at relatively the same time as x2.  How would you go about that.  I know I can use correlation to measure the general relationship.

But is there a way to isolate periods during which they were moving together, from periods during which they deviated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example were we calculate the rolling correlation in a 30 day window, and then plot the result:

```
library(zoo)
roll.corrs <- rollapplyr(dates, 30, function(index) cor(df1[index, "x1"], df1[index, "x2"]), fill=NA)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(as.Date(dates), roll.corrs)
```

or, shorter:

```
z <- zoo(df1, as.Date(rownames(df1)))
r <- rollapplyr(z, 30, function(x) cor(x[,1], x[,2]), by.column = FALSE) 
autoplot(r)
```

The `qplot` output shows:
[image]

You can clearly see how there are in particular two sections with particularly high correlations between the time series.  The data is purposefully designed to have periods of high and low correlation.  Here is the data:

```
base <- c(rep(1, 100), 1:50, rep(50, 100), 50:1, rep(1, 65))
dates <- as.character(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), len=365, by="1 day"))

set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(  
  x1=base+rnorm(365, 0, 5),
  x2=base+rnorm(365, 0, 5),
  row.names=dates
)
```

Comment: This looks much more like it! thanks BordieG.  This is beautiful!

Comment: in r <- rollapplyr(dates, 30, function(index).... Did you mean rollapply() function without the last letter "r".  Zoo doesn't have a rollapplyr function.

Comment: @user2004820, it does.  Look for the documentation for `rollapply`, then in the Usage section, look at the last example, or alternatively, the last paragraph of the Details section.

Comment: got it thanks, I am attaching the comment from Zoo.pdf for the benefit of other users. rollapplyr is a wrapper around rollapply that uses a default of align = "right"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the correlation within subintervals of your overall timeseries?  Then you have to decide what size to make the subintervals, perhaps set a condition for "sufficient correlation", etc.

---

Edit - another idea - one could define a function `F(tau)` which is the correlation between the two timeseries in the `[0,tau]` subinterval, and look at the derivative of it?  But this maybe assumes that it's well-correlated around T = 0 anyway.

Maybe one could find "seed" times where the two are well correlated, and then grow the intervals around it by defining such `G(width)` as correlation in `[seed, seed + width]`) and similarly examining the derivative with respect to width?

Comment: It vaguely occurred to me that I could probably divide my series up and calculate correlation on the pieces. But because of the possible overlapping and the vague size of the interval I quickly discarded it.  I guess I will consider it now as it seems there isn't a quicker way.